# Understanding syntax for compareTo() method in Java

Tags: java, object, comparable, compareto

I have created a `Student` class, which contains roll number, name and age as its data variables. I created an `ArrayList` for storing multiple objects of class `Student`.

Now, I have used the `Comparable` interface and its `compareTo` method to sort the Student list data according to age.

Below is the `compareTo` method I have created for sorting age wise:

```
    public int compareTo(Student sNew)
    {
        return this.age-sNew.age;
    }
```

Here, I can not understand, What is `-`? and How it's working?

Because, I have also done it as below :

```
public int compareTo(Student sNew)
    {
        int returnValue=0;
        if(this.age>sNew.age)
        {
            returnValue=1;
        }else if(this.age<sNew.age){
            returnValue=-1;
        }else if(this.age==sNew.age)
        {
            returnValue=0;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

**So, I have two doubts : How '-' is working in compareTo() method and where it returns the value (0,1,-1).**

Please guide.

Comment: as long as it returns **negative number**, **0**, **positive number** it is fine. That is why you can simply subtract `a.age` from `b.age` when comparing `a` with `b`

Comment: There are only three possible results, unfortunately not defined by an `enum` but by an `int`. A negative number means the instance compared to another one is smaller that the other one, a positive result means it's greater and a zero means they are equal. This is used to define a sorting order for instances of classes, which are not easily sortable as numbers are, for example. It does not give you a qualified information about the reasons and a 0 as its result does not necessarily mean the method `equals()` would return `true`.

Comment: Can't getting. please explain in details

Comment: How it work internally, Who catches the value returned by the compareTo ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind it is that `compareTo` doesn't return 0,1,-1, but returns 0 (equals), positive number (bigger than) or negative (smaller).

For that reason, simply subtracting the ages will give you the correct answer

Comment: Please explain in details

Comment: @JaiminModi look at the contract for `Comaparable.compareTo`: returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. This means, you don't have to return 1, it can be any positive number. so instead of `if a>b return 1`, you can simply return `a-b` (since a>b means the results will be positive)

Comment: What is :: in case of Comparator.comparing(Student::getName); ?

Comment: @JaiminModi it's method reference. see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-colon-operator-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparable` interface is the way Java performs a [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

A trick to get sense of the semantics of `compareTo` is: `a.compareTo(b)` is equivalent to the question *How is a compared to b?* There can be only three answers ([law of trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics))): *a is less than b* (`compareTo()` returns a less than zero value), *a equals b* (`compareTo` returns a zero value), and *a is greater than b* (`compareTo` returns a greater than zero value).

For the case of [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) types (integers, floating-point numbers, dates, etc), the operation a - b always works because of:

- If a < b, the operation a - b will always produce a less than zero value
- If a = b, the operation a - b will always produce zero
- If a > b, the operation a - b will always produce a greater than zero value

In Java syntax, a is the current (`this` object), so the syntax is `a.compareTo(b)`, but the idea is the same.